# Limit disk size uTorrent may use

Tags: windows-7, utorrent

uTorrent has many features for controlling upload and download rates and such but I can't find a setting that will stop it from filling up the HD.  I'd like to be able to tell it to stop when only 1GB is free on the HD.  Is there any setting for this in any version?  If not uTorrent, is there a torrent client that does?

Looking to avoid giving it a separate partition if possible.

I'm trying to automatically avoid the way filling the HD slows my system to a crawl (to the point of waiting minutes for the cursor in a cmd window to blink) forcing me to delete and run chkdsk to get it back

Comment: What OS? Windows ? What version?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek updated

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I limit the disk size uTorrent may use?

If you enable "Pre-allocate all files" then you will be able to easily check how much disk space is remaining using `dir` or `explorer`.

In addition, when adding a torrent `uTorrent` warns you if there is insufficient space remaining on the drive.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't allow me to set a buffer.  I'm trying to avoid the way filling the HD slows my system to a crawl (to the point of waiting for the cursor to blink in a cmd window) forcing me to delete and run chkdsk to get it back. Pre-allocating doesn't stop that from happening.  It just makes it happen sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of a hack, and it isn't utorrent specific, but you might be able to [set a disk quota](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938945.aspx) for your *user* smaller than the amount of space you're using. You'll need to take into account non user space (or somehow run utorrent as its own user, with its own quota), or set a considerably smaller quotaed space than your drive. Simply rightclick on your drive, select quota, and follow through. You can set warnings or a hard limit to ensure you have not used more than a certain amount of space.

[image]

With windows 7 pro, another option might be to create a VHD, and use that to store your torrents on. Its "giving it a seperate partition" but it dosen't actually mean re-sizing your drive, and it lets you create and destroy these VHDs dynamically. [You can create and attach VHDs from the disk management mmc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872416.aspx).

Both these arn't to the 'letter' of what your question asks for but are probably alternatives worth considering that could solve your space woes.

Comment: Seems perfect!  The OS will still have room to play after my user can't write anything new.  I've set a quota.  Will experiment and see if this resolves the problem.  I'll let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd also add, with recent [news on utorrent](http://www.engadget.com/2015/03/06/utorrent-bitcoin-miner/), I'd be considering another torrent client in your shoes. That's entirely tangential to the question though. I tend to use qbitorrent these days. Not as light as the *original* old and awesome utorrent, but does the job

Comment: Nasty.  Thanks for the heads up. I stopped letting uTorrent update when they started pushing add's at us.